# Can two different matrices with the same set of unique eigenvalues have different eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If so, is there something that can be said about a relationship between the set of eigenvectors of the first matrix and the set of eigenvectors of the second matrix? For example, if the answer to the above question is yes, is it true that the pairwise angles between eigenvectors remains fixed for every matrix with the same set of unique eigenvalues?

Comment: Just pick two disjoint orthonormal bases of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Recall the notion of similarity. Similar matrices will have the same eigenvalues, but different eigenvectors. Adjusting the matrix by which you conjugate allows you to choose these eienvectors freely.

Comment: Oh yeah of course, so given a matrix with a set of unique eigenvalues, with a change of basis it is possible to give it any arbitrary set of eigenvectors as long as they form a basis.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$ have the same set of eigenvalues (with the same multiplicity) but they don't even have the same *number* of linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: @Rahul yes but that is precisely why I specified unique eigenvalues.

Comment: By the way, even if you can squeeze the whole question into the title, it is good practice to repeat it in the body of the question with the terminology more fully explained. That way folks like @Rahul (and me) won't miss the subtlety which that one word "unique" entails.

Comment: @LeeMosher Sorry about that. You are totally right. I just happen to be out and only have my phone to ask the question with for a long period of time. Latex on a phone is very time consuming. I'll be more thoughtful of that point in the future though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Let's consider a n-by-n matrix $A$ and $P$ a n-by-n invertible matrix $P$

thus $$B=P^{-1}AP$$

has the same set of eigenvalus but diffirent eigenvectors.

Infact if $Av = \lambda v$

$$BP^{-1}= P^{-1}A$$

then $$BP^{-1}v =P^{-1}Av =\lambda P^{-1}v \ \implies \ B(P^{-1}v) = \lambda (P^{-1}v)$$

A and B are defined as **similar matrices**.

Comment: In particular, when $P$ is orthogonal, angles between the eigenvectors are preserved.

Comment: oh yes of course I've swapped the P's, I correct the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks taking the time to write this out. I had this in the back of my mind somewhere but for some reason I wasn't thinking about how a change of basis leaves the eigenvalues unchanged and obviously changes the eigenvectors until @TheoBendit mentioned it.